# Button wont disable

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I wanted to when I click on a button is background image change to other one and when I release the button goes back to his original image. After a lot of research I found this  [tutorial](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-buttonimage), that helped me lot and works just fine! But the problem is that I can't disable the button, it shows that it is disabled, but if I click on it, it works just like it wasn't disabled! Here is the part of the code

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace DotNetApp
{
    public partial class ButtonImage
    {
        #region Fields

        public new static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsEnabled", typeof (bool), typeof (ButtonImage), null);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof (string), typeof (ButtonImage), null);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImagePressedSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImagePressedSource", typeof (string), typeof (ButtonImage), null);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageDisabledSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageDisabledSource", typeof (string), typeof (ButtonImage), null);

        private BitmapImage _image;
        private BitmapImage _imagePressed;
        private BitmapImage _imageDisabled;
        private bool _isPressed;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public ButtonImage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public new bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledProperty); }

            set
            {
                SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);

                SetImageFromState();
            }
        }

        public string ImageSource
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }

            set
            {
                SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);

                _image = SetImage(value);
                SetImageFromState();
            }
        }

        public string ImagePressedSource
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(ImagePressedSourceProperty); }

            set
            {
                SetValue(ImagePressedSourceProperty, value);

                _imagePressed = SetImage(value);
                SetImageFromState();
            }
        }

        public string ImageDisabledSource
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(ImageDisabledSourceProperty); }

            set
            {
                SetValue(ImageDisabledSourceProperty, value);

                _imageDisabled = SetImage(value);
                SetImageFromState();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Event Handlers

        private void ButtonIsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetImageFromState();
        }

        private void ButtonMouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _isPressed = true;

            SetImageFromState();
        }

        private void ButtonMouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _isPressed = false;

            SetImageFromState();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        private static BitmapImage SetImage(string imageSource)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageSource))
            {
                bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageSource, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }

            return bitmapImage;
        }

        private void SetImageFromState()
        {
            if (!IsEnabled)
            {
                image.Source = _imageDisabled;
            }
            else if (_isPressed)
            {
                image.Source = _imagePressed;
            }
            else
            {
                image.Source = _image;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML

```
<Tap_Test:ButtonImage ImageSource="/images/buttons/star2.png"
                              ImageDisabledSource="/images/buttons/star2lock.png"
                              ImagePressedSource="/images/buttons/star2-2.png"
                              Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}"
                              x:Name="star2" Margin="136,80,134,480" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="star2_Click" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

You can view the full code on the link I provided! I have tried `star2.IsEnable = false;` as well and it didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the fact that the "SetImageFromState()" method is always run, you need a way to stop it from running, consider this:

```
private bool _disableButton;

public bool disableButton { 
                              get { return _disableButton; }
                              set { 
                                     _disableButton = value;
                                     SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, !_disableButton);           

                                  } 
                             }

public new bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledProperty); }

        set
        {
            if(!disableButton)
             {
                SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
                SetImageFromState();
             }


        }
    }
```

So if you wanted to disable truly the button you would go

```
myButton.disableButton = true;
```

Comment: Hi @KillaKem  thanks for helping me, but is coming up with this error App.ButtonImage.disableButtton.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial. Any idea why?

Comment: The compiler wants a body for the disableButton's getter, check to see if the edited code fixes the problem.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks but still the button don't get disabled :( I can still click on it.

Comment: Look at the code edit and try again.Supposed to be "SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, !_disableButton);"

Comment: Still not working :/ same thing bro any ideas? I'm thinking to do in a different way using 2 buttons

Comment: You must be doing something in your "Somestar2_Click" event handler, post that method so we can see what it's doing.

Comment: private void star2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/2star/Level1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

Comment: So maybe I don't understand you, are you saying "myButton.disableButton = true" disables the button but then when you click the button after, the button is enabled again?

Comment: As you can see in the tutorial I posted, we can set a image for each states of the button, enable, disabled and pressed, in theory the button is disabled but in practical it don't work as one, because if you press it still direct you to the next xaml, what I'm trying to do is disabled it for all so when I click don't happen anything.

Comment: Forgot to mention, so yeah when I click instead of the button be unable to run the event it change the status from the button to disabled to enabled and I know because the background image of the button changes.

Comment: Try and disable the button by calling the base.isEnabled property ( see edited code) , if that doesn't work then I think you might have to consider a solution that doesn't override the isEnabled functionality.

Comment: Didn't work, well thanks anyway bro for trying to help me! I think I will do in a different way where I will put a new button above it and remove the pressed effect so when I want to use the star2 i will hide the other button.